# Sprout Forms - An unknown error occurred when trying to view entries in CP

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I've installed Sprout Forms and created a contact form. I'm using displayForm to display the contact form.

The front end appears it's working as it should. Validation works and the success message works when submitting.

The issues are I'm not receiving any email notifications (I have defined my email under Notifications > Email Recipients) and I am unable to view entries under the Sprout Forms control panel. When I click on the Sprout Forms tab, I get an orange prompt that flashes "An unknown error occurred" then disappears.

An odd but promising clue is in the admin, when I click on Sprout Forms then Forms, my contact form is showing the total entries that I've been submitting.

I have tested that PHP Mail works. Does anyone have any clue as to what could be causing this?

Comment: If you check in the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder, the underlying error will be getting logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same problem. update the plugin to version 0.8.3 fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

You're experiencing two different things.

First, as Johannes suggested, if you update to the latest version of the plugin (using the same url that you were sent for the private beta), the error in the control panel will be fixed.  This issue was introduced in Craft 2.3 and was resolved in Sprout Forms 0.8.3

Second, it sounds like you have some issues with Email Notifications.  Assuming you have all the Form Notification settings in place and functioning email, as it sounds like you do, we recently discovered a bug where email notifications are not sent if you are using ajax to submit your forms.  We have a fix we can send you, and it should be resolved once we have a chance to release that and a few other fixes in Sprout Forms 0.8.4

Please send us a note if you have any more questions and we'll get you the updated file if you need it before we get those updates into the next release.

Ben

Comment: The upgrade fixed my error and allowed me to view the entries. Thank you. I'll email you shortly for the email notifications fix.